# Should html-5 and html be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While [html-5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html-5) is not exactly [html](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), as far as security they should probably be combined (I saw that some of the [html-5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html-5) are probably just [html](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, no.
HTML 5 does have it's own set of unique security issues, completely seperate from those existing in "standard" HTML.
Though I don't think there would be that many core HTML security questions...

Yup, after just checking, there are more HTML 5 questions - and they are mostly specific to 5, that would not apply to non-5 HTML.

So, no. :-)

Comment: Ok. I understand.